# How to get elasticsearch to perform an exact match query?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

This is a two-part question.

My documents look like this:

```
{"url": "https://someurl.com", 
 "content": "searchable content here", 
 "hash": "c54cc9cdd4a79ca10a891b8d1b7783c295455040", 
 "headings": "more searchable content", 
 "title": "Page Title"}
```

My first question is how to retrieve all documents where 'title' is *exactly* "No Title".  I don't want a document with the title of "This Document Has No Title" to appear.

My second question is how to retrieve all documents where 'url' appears *exactly* in a long list of urls.

I'm using pyelasticsearch, but a generic answer in curl would also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your source stored (which is the default) you can use a [script filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/script-filter.html)

It should go something like this:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index/type/1 -d '{"foo": "bar"}'
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index/type/2 -d '{"foo": "bar baz"}'
$ curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index/type/_search?pretty=true -d '{
"filter": {
    "script": {
        "script": "_source.foo == \"bar\""
    }
}
}'
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "index",
      "_type" : "type",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0, "_source" : {"foo": "bar"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: I think it's worth mentioning that the "not_analyzed" mapping should be the faster approach. But if you want both exact and partial matches for this field, I see two options: use scripts or index the data twice (once analyzed, once not analyzed).

Comment: It's important to add that this solution executes the script for *each* document in the index. You should first filter results (e.g. using a string query against the same field, in pseudo code "'foo:bar' AND _source.foo='bar'"). I tested this on an index with 620k documents and speed went from "took 7245" to "took 19"

Comment: By using _source you will kill the performance really badly. There is no point on using an inverted index if you are going to read the whole database. "not_analyzed" or "keyword" would be the way to go. There is a compromise solution though, first you use a normal query, and then you use the script filter. It is posible to do both on the same query, I used to do it to match "c++". Order matters, at least on ES1.7, I think I used to put the script on the inner query.

Answer (score 10):

You have to define a mapping for fields.

If you are looking for exact values (case sensitive), you can set index property to `not_analyzed`.

Something like :

```
"url" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
```

Comment: If your field isn't analyzed, doesn't that imply that elasticsearch will basically do a full-table type of scan to find the document? That seems bad...

Comment: No. Lucene is not a database. It's an index. It does not act like a database.

Comment: @BT "not_analyzed" just means the string would not be tokenized, nor filtered, nor stemmed, etc. It will be indexed as a single token.

Answer (score 8):

try this method. it's work.

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
connection = Elasticsearch([{'host': host, 'port': port}])

elastic_query = json.dumps({
     "query": {
         "match_phrase": {
            "UserName": "name"
          }
      }
 })
result = connection.search(index="test_index", body=elastic_query)
```