# Exact (not substring) matching in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

`{"query":{
    "match" : {
        "content" : "2"
    }
}}` matches all the documents whole content contains the number 2, however I would like the content to be exactly 2, no more no less - think of my requirement in a spirit of Java's String.equals.

Similarly for the second query I would like to match when the document's content is exactly '3 3' and nothing more or less. `{"query":{
    "match" : {
        "content" : "3 3"
    }
}}`

How could I do exact (String.equals) matching in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your index type mapping and sample data, it's hard to answer this directly - but I'll try.

Offhand, I'd say this is similar to this answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867852/382774), where you simply set the `content` field's `index` option to `not_analyzed` in your mapping:

```
"url" : {
    "type" : "string", 
    "index" : "not_analyzed"
}
```

Edit: I wasn't clear enough with my original answer, shown above. I did not mean to imply that you should add the example code to your *query*, I meant that you need to specify in your index type *mapping* that the `url` field is of type `string` and it is indexed but not analyzed (`not_analyzed`).

This tells Elasticsearch to not bother analyzing (tokenizing or token filtering) the field when you're indexing your documents - just store it in the index as it exists in the document.  For more information on mappings, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/ for an intro and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/core-types/ for specifics on `not_analyzed` (tip: search for it on that page).

**Update:**

[Official doc](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings) tells us that in a new version of Elastic search you can't define variable as "not_analyzed", instead of this you should use "keyword".

For the old version elastic:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
  }
```

}

For new version:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "type" "keyword",
    "index": true
  }
}
```

Note that this functionality (keyword type) are from elastic 5.0 and backward compatibility layer is removed from  Elasticsearch 6.0 release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what is the exact syntax for the json query? For example `{"query":{
    "match" : {
        "content" : "2 2"
    }
},
"content" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
}` does not work.

Comment: Before you do any indexing and queries you should put a mapping into ElasticSearch: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/

When you start searching with the data you have stored in ElasticSearch right now you won't find anything because the documents are still analyzed the 'old' way (splittng at white space for example)

Comment: If I define "keyword" or "text" in mapping - I can't decide if I need exact matching or not during the query. So can't I have both of them? Sometimes exact matching and sometimes sub string matching.

Comment: @grep, You want to use 'multi-fields': https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html contains the perfect example for you.

Comment: wow, that's cool. Now I can have both of them: keyword and text! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Official Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

You should use filter instead of match.

```
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : { 
        "filter" : {
            "term" : { 
                "content" : 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you got docs whose content is exact 2, instead of 20 or 2.1

Comment: but it works only for "keyword" type and not for "text" type, does not it?